# Flip Chakra UI MenuList to top

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I want to make the `MenuList` that I added appear on top of the `MenuButton`. Is there any way possible to do that?

[image]

I tried to use position: absolute; but it didn't do anything to the `MenuList`.

here are the code that I wrote:

```
 <Menu>
    <MenuButton as={Button} leftIcon={<MoreHoriz />} bgColor="transparent" aria-label="Options">
        Open
    </MenuButton>
    <MenuList className={Styles.menuList}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem  className={Styles.menuItem}>{option.icon}{option.link}</MenuItem >
        ))}
    </MenuList>
  </Menu>
```

Comment: you must add more detail to your question

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75456886/edit) your question and add the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `placement` prop on the `Menu` component with a value of `top`.

```js
<Menu placement="top">
  ...
</Menu>
```

Comment: it's working.. thank you, but is there any way that i can make it to have more specific position, for example make it a little bit to the right?

Comment: That is a different question but yes! You can use the `offset` prop as mentioned in the [ChakraUI Menu docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/menu/props). You have to provide a array of  two numbers [x,y]